# How to get rid of the CRM 4.0 "new_" prefix

Tags: customization, dynamics-crm

Whenever I'm creating a custom entity in CRM, the type is prefixed with "new_". So are any attributes.  How can this be modified/removed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is the prefix for custom entities and attributes.

To change it:

1. Log into the web interface with an administrator account
2. Select: **Settings** -> **Administration** -> **System Settings**
3. Select the **Customization** tab
4. Change the **Prefix** value

Comment: This doesn't get rid of it, but at least I can change it, thanks.