# CRM custom workflow publisher prefix changed after deployment

Tags: dynamics-crm

We use CRM 2016 SP1. We deployed our latest changes from Dev to QA, staging and production by means of importing a managed solution file. As part of the solution file there is a custom Action workflow (Category = Action) with the publisher prefix set to our company name.

The workflow has been activated and working well in QA and staging but when trying to activate it on production CRM comes up with the error "Unexpected Error". Downloaded error details show the same message.

Upon investigating the workflow in production we realised that its publisher prefix had been changed to "new_". To be more specific, the Process Name property starts with the correct prefix name but the Unique Name property starts with "new_".

We had not made any changes to the workflow in Dev and it was working fine in production prior to the deployment.

So far my research on the Internet on how/why this change has come about and how to fix it has been in vain. So any help is greatly appreciated.
Regards

Comment: check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407717/how-to-get-rid-of-the-crm-4-0-new-prefix

Comment: Unlockedluca. thanks for your reply. I updated my question. Also, the prefix value is not shown in the Customization tab in the suggested answer.

Comment: Seems like there might be some confusion with the publisher on PROD. 
You can see publishers by going to Settings > Customizations > Publishers.
Does a publisher exist on PROD with the same name as the one from DEV, but with the new_ prefix?

Another thing to do would be to extract the managed solution's zip file, find the workflow in the customizations.xml and confirm that the workflow's name is correct in there.

Comment: Aron, thanks for your reply. I checked Settings > Customizations > Publishers. Only the default publisher has its prefix set to "new". Our company publisher prefix is correct. This is the same in staging and production. Also, I have already checked the customization.xml file and noticed that the workflow unique name does not start with a prefix in the xml file. So CRM must set the unique name prefix automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see this link for the solution
https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/p/243572/680715#680715

Answer (score 1):

This is identified as an issue in 2016 SP1.

Check [Link Here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4020021/after-updating-to-dynamics-365-mismatched-business-process-flow-entity)

The solution is to Recreate the Process with correct Prefix and delete the one which start with *new_* that to before final deployment/packaging/release.

It is observed that even both processes has different prefix they are identified as same process.

Comment: Sushant. Thanks for your reply. I had not seen that article before. Although it could have something to do with our problem, but during the import to production, we did not encounter any error. So I don't know how relevant that might be to our problem.